# does python stores similar objects at contiguous memory locations?

Tags: python, memory-management, storage, contiguous

Does Python stores similar objects at memory locations nearer to each other?
Because `id` of similar objects, say `lists` and `tuples`, are nearer to each other than an object of type `str`.

Comment: The only correct answer you'll get is "It depends on the implementation" - memory usage isn't defined in the python specification.  If you think it might be important to your code, you're probably using the wrong language.

Comment: its dynamic, it may be but not necessary. it keeps variabl/object in dict

Comment: and dict elements are not in continues memory allocation

Answer (score 4):

No, except of course by coincidence. While this is highly implementation- and environment-specific, and there are actually memory management schemes which would dedicate page-sized memory regions to objects of the same type, no Python implementations I'm aware of exhibits the behavior you describe. With the possible exception of small numbers, which are sometimes cached under the hood and will likely be located next to each other.

What you're seeing *may* be because string literals are created at import time (part of the constants in the byte code) and interned, while lists and tuples (that don't contain literals) are created while running code. If a bunch of memory is allocated in between (*especially* if it isn't freed), the state of the heap may be sufficiently different that quite different addresses are handed out when you're checking.